# How to do Second Minimum in prolog

Tags: prolog

I need help to fix this problem in prolog please,

> Define a predicate secondMin/2 with the signature secondMin(List,
>   Min2) where Min2 is the second lowest unique valued element in some
>   list of numbers, List. If the list has fewer than two unique elements,
>   then your predicate should display the following, “ERROR: List has
>   fewer than two unique elements.” If one more elements of List is not a
>   number, then your predicate should display the following for the first
>   encounter of a non-number element, “ERROR: "element" is not a
>   number.”, where element is the value of the non-number element.

in prolog when I write this:

```
secondMin([512], M2).
```

I have to receive this :

```
ERROR: List has fewer than two unique elements.
```

but in my code is receive this

```
Unknown message: 'List has fewer than two unique elements'
```

have to be error not Unknown message

this what I have

```
%4) Second Minimum
secondMin(L, M) :-
    (   ground(L)
    ->  (   is_list(L),
            maplist(number, L)
        ->  (   sort(L, [_,Second|_])
            ->  M = Second
            ;   throw('List has fewer than two unique elements')
            )
        ;   throw('"b" is not a number')
        )
    ;   throw(error(instantiation_error, _))
    ).
```

Comment: The title of your question has nothing to do with your actual question.

Comment: I take it that this is a classroom assignment or similar, because you are seeking an exact wording, e.g. `ERROR: ` instead of `Unknown message:` As I am not familiar with all Prologs I can not be sure that you are required to use a specific Prolog and that Prolog can return that message as part of something built-in. However I don't believe that to be 100% accurate and that it is your code that needs to return the `ERROR: ` part. If so then ask yourself what is causing `Unknown message: ` and how to change it. I would look at how to remove using `throw()` . Continued.

Comment: Your code shows that you are thinking procedurally, e.g. `if then` or in Prolog `( -> ; )` and in exceptions, when you need to think in terms or predicates and relationships. The core of your problem is that you need to understand how to work with list in Prolog. I would suggest looking at [Learn Prolog Now! - Lists](http://www.learnprolognow.org/lpnpage.php?pagetype=html&pageid=lpn-htmlse13) and working through all the examples, then come back to your problem without using your existing code but starting with a totally new program.

Comment: I am using swish https://swish.swi-prolog.org

Comment: The reason you are not getting answers is that many people including me view this as homework and at StackOverflow we typically don't give the answer to homework but guidance on how to find the answer yourself. Have you learned anything more about this since you asked, and if so put that in the question and ask a question about where you are stuck. If you are waiting for us to do something else without something added to the question, you will probably be waiting past the time the assignment is to be turned in.

Comment: its ok thanks a lot

Comment: `throw/1` isn't looking for a user error message as an argument. It's looking for an *exception*. You actually used `throw/1` correctly once of the three times you used it. Read the full documentation for [`throw/1`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=throw/1) and [`catch/3`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=catch/3) if you want to use exceptions to do this. If you want to take the easy way out, use `write('message'), !, fail`.